# Как я могу получить возвращенные значения из web.api в mvc с помощью json?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Как я могу получить возвращенные значения из web.api в mvc с помощью json?

Код из mvc controller:

```
try
{
    HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
    cl.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:35936");
    cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiUser", "User");
    cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Password", "Password");
    cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MyVar", "1234");
    cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));               
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testedVar);
    var sucSender = await cl.PostAsJsonAsync("api/sender/successtested", json);
    if (sucSender.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       var newvar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tested>(sucSender.ToString());                 
    } 
}
```

И код из Web.Api:

```
string forReturn = "222444";
Tested forRetVar = new Tested
{
    test = forReturn
};
var test123 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(forRetVar);
return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(forRetVar);
```